# Using ForEach with a an array of Bindings (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

My objective is to dynamically generate a form from JSON. I've got everything put together except for generating the FormField views (TextField based) with bindings to a dynamically generated list of view models.

If I swap out the FormField views for just normal Text views it works fine (see screenshot):

```
ForEach(viewModel.viewModels) { vm in
    Text(vm.placeholder)
}
```

for

```
ForEach(viewModel.viewModels) { vm in
     FormField(viewModel: $vm)
}
```

I've tried to make the `viewModels` property of `ConfigurableFormViewModel` an @State var, but it loses its codability. JSON > Binding<[FormFieldViewModel] naturally doesn't really work.

Here's the gist of my [code](https://gist.github.com/erd-s/7351e32569754f8b7eeff91bb7dd150c):

[image: Screenshot of form from JSON but using <code>Text</code>]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trying a different approach. The FormField maintains it's own internal state and publishes (via completion) when its text is committed:

```
struct FormField : View {
    @State private var output: String = ""
    let viewModel: FormFieldViewModel
    var didUpdateText: (String) -> ()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField($output, placeholder: Text(viewModel.placeholder), onCommit: {
                self.didUpdateText(self.output)
            })

            Line(color: Color.lightGray)
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

```
ForEach(viewModel.viewModels) { vm in
    FormField(viewModel: vm) { (output) in
        vm.output = output
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'TextField<_>' with an argument list of type '(Binding<String>, placeholder: Text, onCommit: @escaping () -> ())'` error while doing this. Is that only me?

Comment: @nicoyuste the signatures may be different now... this code is from one of the earlier releases

Comment: I added a new response on the thread with the code that works now.

Answer (score 25):

The first thing that you can try is this:

```
ForEach(0 ..< numberOfItems) { index in
   HStack {
     TextField("PlaceHolder", text: Binding(
       get: { return items[index] },
       set: { (newValue) in return self.items[index] = newValue}
     ))
   }
}
```

The problem with the previous approach is that if `numberOfItems` is some how dynamic and could change because of an action of a Button for example, it is not going to work and it is going to throw the following error: `ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, HStack<TextField<Text>>> count (3) != its initial count (0). 'ForEach(_:content:)' should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to 'Identifiable' or use 'ForEach(_:id:content:)' and provide an explicit 'id'!`

If you have that use case, you can do something like this, it will work even if the items are increasing or decreasing during the lifecycle of the SwiftView:

```
ForEach(items.indices, id:\.self ){ index in
   HStack {
     TextField("PlaceHolder", text: Binding(
       get: { return items[index] },
       set: { (newValue) in return self.items[index] = newValue}
     ))
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this answer! You can also do `self.$items[index]` instead of creating a custom `Binding`.

Comment: Lifesaver - works like a charm. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Be aware: ForEach views only work with static content when you use the index values this way. If you change your content dynamically, you may experience errors.

Answer (score 12):

## Swift 5.5

From Swift 5.5 version, you can use binding array directly by passing in the bindable like this.

```
ForEach($viewModel.viewModels, id: \.self) { $vm in
     FormField(viewModel: $vm)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution could be the following:

```
ForEach(viewModel.viewModels.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
     FormField(viewModel:  self.$viewModel.viewModels[idx])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Took some time to figure out a solution to this puzzle. IMHO, it's a major omission, especially with SwiftUI Apps proposing documents that has models in `struct` and using `Binding` to detect changes.

It's not cute, and it takes a lot of CPU time, so I would not use this for large arrays, but this actually has the intended result, and, unless someone points out an error, it follows the intent of the `ForEach` limitation, which is to only reuse if the `Identifiable` element is identical.

```
ForEach(viewModel.viewModels) { vm in
    ViewBuilder.buildBlock(viewModel.viewModels.firstIndex(of: zone) == nil
        ? ViewBuilder.buildEither(first: Spacer())
        : ViewBuilder.buildEither(second: FormField(viewModel: $viewModel.viewModels[viewModel.viewModels.firstIndex(of: vm)!])))
}
```

For reference, the `ViewBuilder.buildBlock` idiom can be done in the root of the `body` element, but if you prefer, you can put this with an `if`.